# how to create a xsl:function that returns a boolean

Tags: function, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to create a xsl:function with a few parameters that can return a boolean, i'm having troubles:

```
<xsl:if test="my:isEqual($Object1, $Object2)">SAME!</xsl:if>

<xsl:function name="my:isEqual">
    <xsl:param name="Object1" />
    <xsl:param name="Object2" />

    <xsl:variable name="Object1PostalCode select="$Object1/PostalCode" />
    <xsl:variable name="Object2PostalCode select="$Object2/PostalCode" />
    <xsl:if test="$Object1PostalCode = $Object2PostalCode">
        !!!What to do here!!!
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to create a xsl:function with a few parameters that can return
>   a boolean, i'm having troubles:

```
<xsl:function name="my:isEqual">
```

Your troubles start even here. As written, nothing guarantees that this function wouldn't return any XDM type of item or sequence of items.

**Rule to remember**: When writing an `xsl:function` do specify its return type. Also specify the types of the parameters. This spares you from run-time-type-mismatch problems. It also gives opportunity for more powerful and aggressive optimization.

**So, don't write the following -- you can have difficult to catch run-time type mismatch problems**:

```
<xsl:function name="my:isEqual">           
  <xsl:param name="Object1" />           
  <xsl:param name="Object2" />
```

**Instead use the full power of XSLT 2.0 and specify the correct types**:

```
<xsl:function name="my:isEqual" as="xs:boolean">           
  <xsl:param name="Object1" as="element()?" />           
  <xsl:param name="Object2" as="element()?" />
```

**Finally, the end of the code**:

```
    <xsl:if test="$Object1PostalCode = $Object2PostalCode">                     
      !!!What to do here!!!                 
    </xsl:if>             
</xsl:function>
```

**Simply return the comparisson - it evaluates exactly to either `true()` or `false()`** :

```
    <xsl:sequence select="$Object1PostalCode eq $Object2PostalCode"/>                     
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Great. The actual test however is a little more complex. is it allowed to make a complex 'select' like this
 <xsl:sequence select="$Object1PostalCode eq $Object2PostalCode and $Object1Street eq $Object2street"/> ?

Comment: @BasHendriks: Still the same -- just output the (evaluated) test, regardless how complicated it is.

Answer (score 6):

You simply want

```
<xsl:sequence select="$Object1PostalCode = $Object2PostalCode"/>
```

instead of the `xsl:if`.